# How to access my iPhone when I can't remember the passcode

Tags: iphone, security, password

I gave my iPhone 6 to my husband, but he forgot the passcode which changed from 4 #s to 6 #s. How can we get into the phone without it affecting my new iPhone?

Comment: Passcodes are per-device, why do you think it affects your new phone if you reset the old one?

Comment: Also, the title asks something else than the question: Do you need help in getting access to the old phone (the one with the forgotten passcode) or do you know the procedure but are worried about potential cross-dependencies?

Comment: Did he forget the passcode before or after re-purposing it for his own use? Is there a backup? Is it on FindMy?